# iOS, accessing files saved on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ipad, pdf

I am creating an app where it is a requirement to save a pdf with some info the user has put in, so the user can later on retreive this PDF and save it locally outside of the iPad.

The problem is that I cant figure out where the user will be able to find the saved PDF once it is connected to either a PC or a Mac. When running on the emulator I am able to see the PDF fine, but not when working on an actual device - so this basicly means that clearly the PDF is being saved correctly but it just wont show up in explore/itunes/whatever.

I would very much appriciate any input or ideas on what I could do. If I need to clarify the problem more let me know.

Thanks
~Rasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to explore enabling iTunes file sharing in your app. Here's one blog post that explains some of the steps: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app .

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. According to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW20 this will however only allow file shareing via iTunes - How would I go about being able to simply use explorer in windows for file sharing?

Comment: I think that may need jailbreaking the phone. iOS doesn't have a file system in the same sense as Mac OS or Windows where files get saved in a common directory hierarchy. The pdf's in your case are saved within the sandbox of your app.

Comment: Hm - So there would be no reason to simply save the pdf in the same folder as when taking photos for example? I would really like avoid using iTunes (or jailbreaking) if it is at all possible. Once again thanks for the reply.